# How to convert list<SomeType> to map keeping all duplicate key and values

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, java-8

I had a list as below :

```
List<Address> address;
```

where

```
Address:
city
country
state
```

I want to convert it into something like below

```
Map <String,String> convertedMap=list.stream().collect
(Collectors.toMap(Address:getCity+Address:getCountry ,Address:getState));
```

I want to keep all duplicate key and values in the generated map as below .

```
(key=City1country1, value= state1) ,(key=City1country1, value=state2),(key=City1country1,value= state1) ;
```

Comment: That's not how a map works. A map has unique keys. You can't have multiple keys the same. If you want to now all the states for a particular city/country combo, your map could be from city/country to list of states: `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, maps do not store duplicated keys so you have to use `Map<String, List<String>>` instead `Map<String, String>`.

To sum up, you just have to use `Collectors.toMap` method with `mergeFunction` parameter where you can handle duplicated keys. This operation will be called every time when same keys appears. In this case, we simply merge two lists to one. Have a look at below code (compiled with JDK 11), I believe it does exactly what you need and prints an expected result (using `List<String>` of course).

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListToMapWithDuplicatedKeysSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Address> addresses = List.of(
                new Address("City1", "country1", "state1"),
                new Address("City1", "country1", "state2"),
                new Address("City1", "country1", "state1"),
                new Address("City3", "country3", "state3")
        );
        Map<String, List<String>> result = addresses.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                address -> address.getCity() + address.getCountry(),
                                address -> Collections.singletonList(address.getState()),
                                ListToMapWithDuplicatedKeysSample::mergeEntriesWithDuplicatedKeys
                        )
                );
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static List<String> mergeEntriesWithDuplicatedKeys(List<String> existingResults, List<String> newResults) {
        List<String> mergedResults = new ArrayList<>();
        mergedResults.addAll(existingResults);
        mergedResults.addAll(newResults);
        return mergedResults;
    }

    private static class Address {

        private final String city;
        private final String country;
        private final String state;

        public Address(String city, String country, String state) {
            this.city = city;
            this.country = country;
            this.state = state;
        }

        String getState() {
            return state;
        }

        String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t use Collectors.toMap, because it requires unique keys.  What you want instead is groupingBy, which returns collected values for each key:

```
class Location {
    public final String city;
    public final String country;

    Location(Address address) {
        this.city = address.getCity();
        this.country = address.getCountry();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Location) {
            Location other = (Location) obj;
            return Objects.equals(this.city, other.city) &&
                   Objects.equals(this.country, other.country);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(city, country);
    }
}

Map<Location, Set<String>> statesByLocation = addresses.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Location::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Address::getState, Collectors.toSet())));
```

You *could* employ various hacks for combining city and country (like a list of two Strings), but you really should just make a key class as shown above.  The code will be far easier to work with, especially if you (or another developer) should have a reason to come back to it in six months.

As for the Collector methods:

- `Collectors.groupingBy(Location::new` is equivalent to `address -> new Location(address)` and creates each key in the Map.
- `Collectors.mapping(Address::getState, Collectors.toSet())` means that each Address which corresponds to a particular key will have getState() invoked on it, and the resulting strings will be aggregated in a Set to form the Map value.

Personally, I think I would opt for a simple for-loop instead of the hard-to-read Stream approach:

```
Map<Location, Set<String>> statesByLocation = new HashMap<>();
for (Address address : addresses) {
    statesByLocation.computeIfAbsent(new Location(address),
        k -> new HashSet<String>()).add(address.getState());
}
```

Comment: @malverndongeni Feel free to comment on things I may have missed.  Commenting is better than editing directly, usually.

Comment: there is a  **Collector.toMap**  method that allows duplicates on keys with the following method signature    **toMap(Function k, Function v,BinaryOperator m)**         _Returns a Collector that accumulates elements into a Map whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided mapping functions to the input elements_

Comment: @malverndongeni There is no such thing as a Map with duplicate keys.  The very definition of a Map is that keys are unique.  I addressed this in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: i do agree..on my comment there is typo error suppose to be values.The method used l throws IllegalStateException if it encounters duplicate key.However,there is an option to specify what to if there is a duplicate key.Which will give the desired output using lambda's..check my solution below

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing is a common requirement for lots of coding challenges, here is a quick way to accomplish what you need if you have time constraints, I chose to use a set rather than a list for the lookup time to be O(1) rather than O(N):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class MapExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> addressesList = new ArrayList<>();
    addressesList.add("Portland USA ME");
    addressesList.add("Portland USA OR");
    addressesList.add("Boston USA MA");
    System.out.println(cityToStatesMap(addressesList));
  }

  private static Map<String, Set<String>> cityToStatesMap(List<String> addressesList) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    if (addressesList == null || addressesList.size() == 0) {
      return result;
    }
    for (String address : addressesList) {
      String[] addressComponents = address.split(" ");
      String city = addressComponents[0];
      String country = addressComponents[1];
      String state = addressComponents[2];
      String key = city + country;
      Set<String> states = result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>());
      states.add(state);
      result.put(key, states);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{PortlandUSA=[ME, OR], BostonUSA=[MA]}
```

*Note: I think you should use something like a `,` for a delimiter rather than a space so it will be easier to deal with cities with multiple words e.g. New York, San Francisco etc.*

Answer (score 0):

use the toMap with the following method signature

```
   toMap(Function k, Function v,BinaryOperator m)
```

**BinaryOperator** informs the JVM on what to do if it encounters duplicates keys. In your case if it encounters duplicates it is suppose to concat them.

thus **s1 +","+s2**

hence your solution becomes

```
  Map<String, String> map = list.stream().
            collect(Collectors.toMap((address -> {
                String y = address.getCity() + address.getCountry();
                return y + s;
            }), Address::getState, (s1, s2) -> s1 + "," + s2));
```

**output**

```
     country3City3  state3
     country1City1  state1,state2,state1

      Process finished with exit code 0
```